# PhoneGap android: getting cannot create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: java, android, exception, android-activity, phonegap-plugins

I created a `PhoneGap` plugin for android which sends an `email`.

```
public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray args, String callbackId) {
    try {
        // i want to call a function from other class so i did the
        // below, but it is throwing  the above said error...

        WebActivity wb = new WebActivity();
        wb.createExternalStoragePrivateFile(img);

        //sending email code here
    }
}
```

In above code while accessing the function of another class , i am getting the error:

> cannot create `handler` inside thread that has not called `Looper.prepare()` error.

What is the right approach to call the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `WebActivity` is actually an activity (i.e. extends `Activity`), you have several things wrong.

---

You must not create `Activity` objects yourself. Well, you can, but than you have to assign a context to them (which I'm not sure even possible without using internals), and manage Activity lifecycle.

You can't just create an Activity object and call a function. This function may have lifecycle and context dependencies (i.e. you may have to "resume" the activity).

---

The error you see is the result of that each `Activity` expects to be called from UI-thread ( or at least from `Looper` thread). The function you call most like uses `Handler` in some way, either directly or indirectly. And when this function creates a `Handler` and then posts a message or `Runnable` you'll get the error you see.

But again, this is because `Activity` is not meant to be used the way you've used. You cannot just create activity and start calling it's method. You basically violate it's state model. So `Activity` is not even supposed to work.

---

As a solution, if you have control over `WebActivity`, move `createExternalStoragePrivateFile()` function into some independent class or make it static (if possible), or both. You most likely will need to fix a thing or two there, to make it work. But at least you'll be able to call the function from other places.

Comment: thanx for the reply ,In the createExternalStoragePrivateFile() function im copying a file which is in assets folder to an external file on the sdcard, 
If i create another independent static class, then how to access the files in the assets folder.. ????

Comment: Pass a context: `createExternakStoragePrivateFile(Context)`. Then you'll be able to access `AssetManager` and copy the file.